# console shows OK but browser showes error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Hi friends i came with a new problem. In my rails app i have a task controller and model.When i try to create a new task i got the error message "due_date" should not be blank, but when i check my console there is a success message.Here is my code:

My Controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  layout "payroll" , :except => [:closed,:today,:this_week, :this_month]

  # GET /tasks
  # GET /tasks.xml
  def index
    @menu = "Timesheet"
    @page_name = "Manage Task"
    company_id = Company.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain)
    @users = User.find_all_by_company_id(company_id)
    @tasks = Task.find_all_by_assigned_to(session[:current_user_id].to_i)#.page(params[:page])
    @task = Task.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @tasks }
    end
  end
 # POST /tasks
  # POST /tasks.xml
  def create
    @task = Task.new(params[:task])
    #@task.assigned_to = session[:user_id]
    @task.task_status = "0"

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
         Email.task_created(@task).deliver
         @tasks = Task.all
         @task = Task.new
         format.html { redirect_to tasks_path }
         format.xml  { render :xml => @task, :status => :created, :location => @task }
      else
         format.html { render :action => "new" }
         format.xml  { render :xml => @task.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My Model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  #validation start 
  validates :description, :due_date, :assigned_to, :priority, :presence => true
  validates_length_of :description, :maximum =>500
 end
```

and View:

```
<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/form_error', :object => @task %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :description %><br />
      <%= f.text_area :description ,:rows => "2", :cols => "20" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :due_date %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :due_date %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :assigned_to %><br />
      <%= collection_select(:task, :assigned_to, User.all, :id, :first_name, :prompt =>true ) %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :priority %><br />
      <%= f.select (:priority, [['High'],['Medium'],['Low']]) %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <button type="submit" class="btn"><img src="/images/add.png" />&nbsp; Add This Task</button>
    </div>
<% end %
```

My console message:

```
Started GET "/tasks" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Nov 19 12:27:10 +0530 2011
  Processing by TasksController#index as HTML
  ←[1m←[36mCompany Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."subdomain" = 'rsgroup'
 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."company_id" = 1
  ←[1m←[36mTask Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."assigned_to" = 1←[0m
Rendered shared/_page_title.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered shared/_no_record.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered tasks/_task_table.html.erb (5.0ms)
Rendered shared/_form_error.html.erb (1.0ms)
  ←[1m←[35mUser Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
Rendered tasks/_form.html.erb (130.0ms)
Rendered shared/_sidebar.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered shared/_payroll_footer.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered tasks/index.html.erb within layouts/payroll (173.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 253ms (Views: 183.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Here i use j query date picker for calender display.But cause of concern is why my task not saved? please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1st step: please show the `POST` data from the error page.

Comment: Also: your console shows a `GET` to the `index` action, but you're talking about `create`?

Comment: Hi jim i render my _form.hml.erb patial to index page, hence this confusion

Comment: I wasn't confused about that. You said the error was on `create`, but the console output clearly shows `index`.

Comment: Hi jim i fixed it. I have missed some java script files to include hence my date field giving this error.thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI friends i came with an answer, I just added few css and java script file's in my public folder and problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code

> `format.xml  { render :xml => @task, :status => :created, :location => @task }`

is called after save and after assignement of `@task = Task.new`.

Also error may be in invalid format of the due_date that is POSTed. As @jimworm requested, provide POST request, not the index page request. From that request we could get the params submitted, and you could try in `rails c` to create the `Date` from submitted string and check if it not be `nil`.

Comment: Hi Mark i agree with you but same code works in my other forms, which doesn't has any date field.It gives problem in only those forms that have any date field.

Comment: Seems like the problem in your date format. Provide the logs on POST request as @jimworm requested.

Comment: In your question you provided Logs on Get request to index page. But your problem in `POST` request to `create` action. So to be sure where your problem with that action it would be helpful to see logs from that request too.

Comment: Hi mark thanks for guidance.I have fixed it, my code is ok i just forgot include some of my supporting java script and css files due to date my date field giving me error.Thanks a lot.